# include .htaccess in another directory into a main .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I was looking at making a folder structure like this

```
htdocs
|--app
   |-- myProject
       |-- index.php
       |-- settings.ini
       |-- .htaccess (project)
|--core
|--index.php
|--config.ini
|--.htaccess (main)
```

I waned some global `.htaccess` rules in the main `.htaccess` file but I wanted some project specific rules in the project `.htaccess`

Is there a way I can have both `.htaccess` fils co-exist? or have the project `.htaccess` file included in the main `.htaccess`?

I know in apache you can include files, because in my `httpd.conf` i have an include statement to include `.conf` files outside of the directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my server I have exactly what you have here. One `.htaccess` file for the `htdocs` folder and one for another site.

I never had any problem, it seems that the `.htaccess` for the project overrides the `.htaccess` for `htdocs`.

Comment: the problem I think I am having is that since the nature of my index.php on the root (htdocs) will control what project gets viewed by including the files from the projects rather than having redirects (or header locations). With that method then the sub level htaccess will never get accessed. So I wanted my main htaccess to load the project htaccess file.